# Python minidom xml parsing to get the value of first child node

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am using python minidom to parse a xml, but not able to get it working for below xml. I want to select the first server tag and want the value of name tag , in this case "Server1"

```
<class>
<name>MyClass</name>
<security>
<name>MyClass</name>
</security>
<server>
<name>Server1</name>
<ssl>
 <name>Server1</name>
</ssl>
<server-info>
 <name>Server1</name>
</server-info>
</server>
<server>
<name>Server2</name>
<ssl>
 <name>Server2</name>
</ssl>
<server-info>
 <name>Server2</name>
</server-info>
</server>
<server>
<name>Server3</name>
<ssl>
 <name>Server3</name>
</ssl>
<server-info>
 <name>Server3</name>
</server-info>
</server>
</class>
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead?

Comment: our servers are running on python 2.4, and we want something which is built in

Comment: That is a valid reason, but I'd look into upgrading the servers ASAP; 2.4 is rather ancient.

Comment: Yeah! All depends on my employer,I need to run it on approx 100 servers and all are like this only.. I don't think it will happen anytime soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to reference the [XML DOM documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html) and grit your teeth.

To get the first `<server>` element, then its `<name>`:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

document = minidom.parse(inputfilename)

def findChildNodeByName(parent, name):
    for node in parent.childNodes:
        if node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE and node.localName == name:
            return node
    return None

def getText(nodelist):
    rc = []
    for node in nodelist:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            rc.append(node.data)
    return ''.join(rc)

# Get the first of all `<server>` nodes
server = document.getElementsByTagName('server')[0]

# Get the first child node that is a `<name>` element
name = findChildNodeByName(server, 'name')
if name is not None:
    print getText(name.childNodes)
```

Comment: it improves with every refresh :)

Comment: @DevC: I tend to avoid minidom if at all possible, my DOM skills are rusty and I keep recalling a few tricks. It has [been a while](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2001JanMar/author.html#msg232) since I had to deal with the standard in earnest.

Comment: something is wrong with next part, either indentation or something.. gotcha next is not in python 2.4

Comment: Plone Metrics Person of the Year 2012 .. I didn't know whom I was talking with.. much respect... I love opensource and deep respect for everyone who contribute to it